# Why does displayLink.timestamp return wrong result?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

In iOS programming we can use CADisplayLink so that our handler is called everytime the screen refreshes. The idea is to advance game/animation state and then draw it into the screen. To get the current time, we can use displayLink.timestamp from the event handler. However, why does it return values that are the same from previous call to the handler when I run it on the device? Because of this I cannot correctly compute the elapsed time since it will be 0.

Finding the time using NSDate works. Running on the simulator works.

Here is the relevant code. Assume you create a single view application from XCode. Then change the header file of the view controller as follows:

```
@interface MBIViewController : UIViewController
{
    float _lastTimeStamp;
    NSDate *_lastDate;
}

-(void)updateView:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink; // using displayLink.timestamp
-(void)updateView2:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink; // using NSDate
@end
```

Then hook the handlers in viewDidLoad:

```
_lastTimeStamp = CACurrentMediaTime();
_lastDate = [NSDate date];

CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateView:)]; // change this to updateView2: to compare
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Then here are the 2 handlers:

```
-(void)updateView:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    float newTimeStamp = displayLink.timestamp;
    float elapsedTime = newTimeStamp - _lastTimeStamp;
    float fps = 1.0f / elapsedTime;
    _lastTimeStamp = newTimeStamp;

    NSLog(@"elapsed time: %f", elapsedTime);   
    NSLog(@"fps: %f", fps);
    NSLog(@"---");
}

-(void)updateView2:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];
    float elapsedTime = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_lastDate];
    float fps = 1.0f / elapsedTime;
    _lastDate = newDate;

    NSLog(@"elapsed time: %f", elapsedTime);
    NSLog(@"fps: %f", fps);
    NSLog(@"---");
}
```

Here's the output of updateView: on the device:

```
2013-07-06 19:07:06.274 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] elapsed time: 0.000000
2013-07-06 19:07:06.281 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] fps: inf
2013-07-06 19:07:06.286 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:07:06.291 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] elapsed time: 0.000000
2013-07-06 19:07:06.298 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] fps: inf
2013-07-06 19:07:06.303 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:07:06.308 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] elapsed time: 0.000000
2013-07-06 19:07:06.315 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] fps: inf
2013-07-06 19:07:06.321 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:07:06.325 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] elapsed time: 0.062500
2013-07-06 19:07:06.329 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] fps: 16.000000
2013-07-06 19:07:06.333 DisplayLinkTest[24842:907] ---
```

When it's correct, it's always 16fps.

Here's what happen if you hook to updateView2: instead:

```
2013-07-06 19:16:03.318 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] elapsed time: 0.016677
2013-07-06 19:16:03.322 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] fps: 59.962959
2013-07-06 19:16:03.325 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:16:03.335 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] elapsed time: 0.016731
2013-07-06 19:16:03.339 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] fps: 59.769207
2013-07-06 19:16:03.342 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:16:03.352 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] elapsed time: 0.017200
2013-07-06 19:16:03.357 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] fps: 58.139557
2013-07-06 19:16:03.365 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] ---
2013-07-06 19:16:03.369 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] elapsed time: 0.017283
2013-07-06 19:16:03.374 DisplayLinkTest[24871:907] fps: 57.860249
```

Am I using displayLink.timestamp incorrectly? Thanks